# Navigation with only Back Button and transparent background

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios-autolayout

I had tried to implement Navigation Controller which embeds in my View Controller. It works as expected.

But my requirement is slightly different which needs only a back button and already have a top banner with logo image background in all the screens . So if I try to implement back button it takes the space for the navigation bar which covers the Logo/top banner.

Is there any way to overcome this scenario .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That seems pretty easy, by the following code used in my app too:-

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

**Edit:-**

To remove back button text:-

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: Thanks Vizlix. I m pretty new to IOS environment. Where should I try this code?

Comment: Write this in root view controller's viewdidload().

Comment: It works . :) Any Idea how to remove Back text from the button since need only icon to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is there any other option or not. But in the past i have same scenario as you.

I have created custom .XIB with UIView. and Add subview it to as Navigationbar.

So, According to me the best option is , create custom .XIB with Height of UINavigation bar. and Add as subview.

Here is step how you can achieve it.

1) Take **.h** file , **.m** file and  **Xib** of UIView with size of **width 46** and **height 44**

2) Set constrain and layout according to your suitable design.

3) Give outlet to Back button in .h file.

4) Create one delegate in customview.h file . set method in .m file.

5) then import customview.h file in your viewcontroller.h file . As same don't forget to define delegate in viewcontrollers interface. <>

6) Now add customheaderview as subview in your Viewdidload method.

```
#define macro_name (Define in constantfile as macro if you don't want to write whole code again and again)

NavigationHeaderview *customView = [NavigationHeaderview CustomNavigation:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.x y:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y width:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width height:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height];
customView.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:customView];
```

7) Access it in your all view controller with delegate method of headerview.

Now you can do anything in navigationbar like you do in UIView.

**Note:-** I know it is tedious process. but it is worth when you need 3 or 4 button in navigation bar and set Action on it . or need same design layout for whole project in navigationbar..

Comment: Thanks Badal for explaining things for me

Comment: Welcome . Happy to Help.