# Embed a UIImageView in a bar widget either at the top or bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

The navigation bar can take a UIImageView via the titleView property,

for example

**self.navigationItem.titleView**, and the The UIImageView can be animated.

Unfortunately, as per the documentation "**Custom title views are centered on the navigation bar and may be resized to fit**". This resizing makes it unsuitable for me.

My **goal** is to **animate** a **UIImageView** in something like a navigation bar, tab bar or toolbar. In other words I want to animate UIImageView in a bar that is always visible in a view.

How would I do this (using swift)?

Comment: I am not sure and i havn't seen animation as you described in question but may be you can try with creating custom view and give animation as accessing it in navigation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35332485/4910767

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a UIBarButtonItem with a UIImageView in the constructor and set the left or right button in the navigator bar to the animate button item.